# JBPM 7.31, automatically skip human task after due date

Tags: process, jbpm, skip

in JBPM is it possible to automatically skip a human task after the due date?

[This is an example of my process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBfjL.png)

In task 'Evaluation' the user can ask for a Contribution, in this case the next task will be 'Contribution'.
The task 'Contribution' has a sla of 2 day.
After this period the process must automatically return to task 'Evaluation'.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using TimerBoundaryEvent for `Contribution` task. Define 2 day sla at TimerBoundaryEvent if UserTask is not completed in 2 days, task will be cancelled and process flow can continue to Gateway or other tasks.